# Api to move row in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can I move a excel row using POI ? For example I need to move `Row5`  to `Row1`. And after moving the rows formulas has to be updated automatically. I tried `shiftRows()`. But `shiftRows()` has limitation. If I am moving one row I can shift up by only one position using `shiftRows()`. If I try to move up the single row by more than one position it is not working.  Is there any other APIs which I can use?

Here is a code snippet where I am having problem with shiftRows()

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        workbook.createSheet("mySheet");
        Row row = workbook.getSheet("mySheet").createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1.0);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(2.0);
        //
        row = workbook.getSheet("mySheet").createRow(1);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1.0);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(2.0);
        row = workbook.getSheet("mySheet").createRow(2);
        row.createCell(0).setCellFormula("SUM(A1,B1)");
        row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("SUM(A1,B1)");
        row = workbook.getSheet("mySheet").createRow(3);
        row.createCell(0).setCellFormula("SUM(A3,B3)");
        row.createCell(1).setCellFormula("SUM(A3,B3)");
        workbook.getSheet("mySheet").shiftRows(3, 3, -2);
```

I am trying to move 4th row up by 2 positions. With this code if I generate excel and try it opening with MS Excel I get prompt which says "We found a problem with  some content in ffdd.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"  If I click yes and open data is not proper. Attached screen shot of the same
[image]

However if I change code  `workbook.getSheet("mySheet").shiftRows(3, 3, -2);` to  `workbook.getSheet("mySheet").shiftRows(3, 3, -1);` generated excel opens fine

Comment: shitftRow() would be the appropriate method, only it proved very hard to get right for all the myriad cases that are possible, if you have a specific case that does not work it would be good to submit a bug-entry for POI together with a small unit-test to make it easy to reproduce and test a fix when it is applied.

Comment: @centic Thanks for the suggestion . Problem with shiftRows() is  if you are shifting 1 row then you can shift by  <= 1 row. And if you are shifting 2 rows you can shift up only  by <=2 rows and so on. Not sure if this is the expected behaviour. Will post a bug..

Comment: You should be able to move an arbitrary number of rows by any distance. Without code we can't help you work out what's going wrong though...

Comment: @Gagravarr  Posted the code. can you please check what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I ran your code, and when the spreadsheet opens, it produces an error in Excel. Inspecting the XML does not provide any hints to me, so I am going to submit a bug for this. That way it will be looked at by more experienced eyes.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy  Thanks for the help. Requesting you to provide a link to the bug so that I can also track it.

Comment: It was already out there, here is a link: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57423